# Get current locale

Tags: sails.js

The question is simple, however I found nothing about it in the docs:

How can I get the current locale for a request? (the locale used for translations with `req.__('to_translate');`)

Is there something like `req.getLocale();` ?

Comment: I tried req.acceptedLanguages but it returned [ 'en-US', 'en', 'fr' ] for my browser, so i don't know if that's exactly what you are looking for.
You have all the requests methods here: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/request-req

Comment: @MarcD That's not what I'm looking for. I'd like to get the selected language (only one) for the current request (and thus the current user session). I also looked at the reference for req but I found nothing. However I still believe there must be a way to get this language because the translation module in sails needs it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, as you stated, you must use `req.getLocale()`

Citing a paragraph from the [sails docs](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/internationalization/locales)

> By default, node-i18n will detect the desired language of a request by
>   examining its language headers. Language headers are set in your
>   users' browser settings, and while they're correct most of the time,
>   you may need the flexibility to override this detected locale and
>   provide your own.

So you should get your locale. eg: `"en"`, if the user that accessed your endpoint, has English configured as its browser language.

Now if you are resetting the locale value in a sails policy, or the controller itself, you might get faulty data if it was set incorrectly, since i assume you already tried the `req.getLocale` method without success, but since you don't provide more data, i can just guess.

Btw, you can access the current locale in your view, by directly accessing to the locale variable (which is eval-ed from the locals.locale object sent to the view, at least in jade views...)

Comment: I'll continue investigating but it appears that we can't get the current locale, we can just override it, so the solution may be to send it from the client side and set it server side in a policy.

Comment: Did you set a default locale in `config/i18n.js`? in case the browser is not sending the "Accept-Language" header. I must admit that i'm using a custom policy that overrides the locale, so i'm not sure if there is a faulty behavior here, if it is it could be a good idea to post an issue on the github repo. In the meantime, if its buggy, then as you said, make a policy to extract the locale from the route, maybe from params like ?lang='fr', or as part of the route path which i use, like mysite.com/fr, or even parsing the headers to do what sails is supposed to do automatically.

Comment: Yes I set a default locale for i18n. I also posted an issue https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/3219

Comment: But the method does exist, I'm using it on a project and it works,  at least when setting it via setLocale on a custom policy and using the default locale,  I didn't test by modifying the headers though. Make sure that you state that you've tried using it but it didn't work. I'm not sure what is failing on your code since you just state that is not possible.  Modify your question to show what is not working,  since what you asked was answered.

Comment: @FabienHenon I just tested the default behavior, by using postman and configuring the `Accept-Language` for different languages, and `req.getLocale()` returns the corresponding locale, so this works as expected, not only when setting the locale on a policy(Which is basically what sails is doing but in a middleware). So this answer should be marked as the correct one. If you have issues with your code, then create a new question and i'll be happy to help.

Comment: You're right. I got an answer from their github and this is the correct answer. Maybe I was using it wrong, I'll investigate on it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

To change the global language of internationalization you must use:

```
sails.hook.i18n.setLocale("locale_code")
```

and in your code you must use:

```
sails.__("string_key")
```

to translate the string. In views you must use:

```
<%= sails.__("string_key") %>
```